# which value precedes when using the new `spring.profiles.group.*` config?

Tags: spring-boot

I have 2 profiles `ci` and `development` which both set a prop `db`. I wonder which values "win" in the new Spring Boot 2.4 config handling when using a `ci` group like this:

```
spring.profiles.group.ci[0]: development 

---

spring:
  config.activate.on-profile: development
  db: a

---

spring:
  config.activate.on-profile: ci
  db: b
```

**Question 1**

If the environment sets the active profile to `ci`, which `db` value would be used? The value defined in `ci` or the one in `development`?

**Question 2**

Does it behave differently from question 1 if the environment sets active profiles explicitly to `development, ci` or `ci, development`?

**Background**

We are trying to migrate from `profiles.include: ...` to the new `spring.profiles.group.*` configuration. Formerly, we had the 'include`statement in the`ci`profile to include the`development`. However, by this itself the` development`variables would override the ones in`ci`- which to my perception is unexpected. Hence, we needed to specify`spring.active.profiles=development,ci`to let the values in`ci`override the ones in`development`. As far as I understood the changes in 2.4. are meant to address this unexpected behavior, but we still do not clearly see how things should behave and how the new config options should be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring boot documentation mentioned about Multi-Profile YAML documents :

```
You can specify multiple profile-specific YAML documents in a single file by using a `spring.profiles` key to indicate when the document applies.
```

For example:

```
server:
    address: 192.168.1.100
---
spring:
    profiles: development
server:
    address: 127.0.0.1
---
spring:
    profiles: production
server:
    address: 192.168.1.120
```

The `server.address` property will be

- `127.0.0.1` if the `development` profile is active.
- `192.168.1.120` if the `production` profile is active.
- If the development and production profiles are `not enabled`, then the value for the
  property will be `192.168.1.100`

You can follow the same analogy to decide the winner.

More Information on changes bring in spring boot 2.4

[Config file processing in Spring Boot 2.4](https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4)

Group defining can be

```
spring.profiles.group.<groupname>=ci,development
```

To use the legacy way of working you can enable the property as :

```
spring.config.use-legacy-processing=true
```

For multi-document Propferties spring boot 2.4 comes with the syntax as (#---)

e.g.

```
test=value
#---
test=overriden-value
```

Migration Document Guidelines

```
If you use multi-document YAML files (files with ---- separators) then you need to be aware that property sources are now added in the order that documents are declared. With Spring Boot 2.3 and earlier, the order that the individual documents were added was based on profile activation order.

If you have properties that override each other, you need to make sure that the property you want to "win" is lower in the file. This means that you may need to reorder the documents inside your YAML.
```

[Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Config-Data-Migration-Guide)

**UPDATE**
I had simulated the multi profile properties
Here is my answer based on the actual executions to your question highlighted

> Question 1
>
> If the environment sets the active profile to ci, which db value would
> be used? The value defined in ci or the one in development?
> ***Answer - db defined in ci***

> Question 2
>
> Does it behave differently from question 1 if the environment sets
> active profiles explicitly to development, ci or ci, development?
> **> It would not behave differently.
> If, you want explicitly to win a particular value define them as lower in document**

Comment: But how does it behave when using the new `group` feature (that replaces the old `includes` feature)? When activating the profile `ci` It enables both, `ci` and `development` but it is not clear to me in which order it happens and which value would win.

Comment: I provided more background and a more extensive example, because your answer currently does not address the question.

Comment: Following the example it is behaving different than it should be
doc says -> the lower document mention will override values in the higher one.
On setting up definition for group, check whether the inclusion acting like creating a member from the profile, instead of treating as a separate.
from -> spring.profiles.group.ci[0]: development 
to - > spring.profiles.group.<groupname>: ci, development

Comment: Yes, you propose to not call the group like the config chunk to make it predictable, But still it is a valid configuration to call it the same. And the question is about what happens in this case.